# Post a relation in a repeatable component on Strapi

Tags: post, strapi, relation

I am trying to post a relation in a repeatable component in Strapi. I receive a 200 but the relation is not added. Here is my structure and my code :

[image]

```
const postData = {
  name,
  locale: "fr",
  summary,
  people,
  preparationInMinutes,
  cookingInMinutes,
  equipments: {
    oven,
    microwave,
    hob,
    mixer,
    thermomix,
    fryer,
  },
  Ingredients: [
    {
      ingredient: 31,
      amount: 100,
      unit: "g",
    },
    {
      ingredient: 32,
      amount: 500,
      unit: "l",
    },
  ],
  Instructions: [
    {
      ingredients: [31, 32],
      step: "étape 1",
    },
    {
      ingredients: [33, 34],
      step: "étape 2",
    },
  ],
  source: 21,
}; 
form.append("data", JSON.stringify(postData));
await axios
  .post(getStrapiURL("/recipes"), form, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
    },
  })
  .then((response) => {
    // Handle success.
    console.log("Well done!");
    console.log("Data: ", response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle error.
    console.log("An error occurred:", error.response);
  });
```

I tried adding the relation with the id, an array of ids. None of these possibilities are working.

NOTE : The relation in the post for the "source" is working since it is not in a repeatable component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanna die, it was just the permissions when I am authenticated. If you're dumb like me, try to go in your Roles and edit the permissions

Comment: oh, don't eat yourself ...